# "Aims" vs. "objectives"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Is there a difference between *aims* and *objectives*?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Could you add to the question the dictionary definitions you have found, and point out the particular cause of difficulty?

Comment: What @BrianHooper says, with the rider that the OP's question is still valid and the answer not as simple as it appears to be. The words are interchangeable in some contexts, not in others.

Comment: An objective is more formal and would generally be more specific and measurable than an aim which is more vague.

Answer (score 1):

This comes close to being one you could research quite easily on your own.

The Wikipedia article at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Educational_aims_and_objectives explains that the answer is almost certainly 'Yes' to your friend but 'Not usually' to someone not in Education. As an educationalist should be aware.

Comment: The OP has not confined his question to a particular domain, though.

Comment: Neither have I confined my answer to a particular domain. Though surely we can deduce that the question is likely to be Education-orientated; if one were to mention stars and stripes, a flag connection might be considered likely.